# How to check raw request content size in Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, gzip

I am posting data from mobile device to web API. The post request JSON are containing picture so I have converted in base64string for post on Web API. I am converting the JSON in GZIP. Below is the code that i am using for send the request from Mobile device to Web API in `XAMARIN FORM PCL`

```
    var jsonPictures = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataOrderPictures);
    using (HttpClientHandler ClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
    using (HttpClient Client = new HttpClient(ClientHandler))
      {                             
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
        var content = new StringContent(jsonPictures, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var result1 = await Client.PostAsync(uri, content);
        var enc = Encoding.UTF8;
        using (Stream responseStream = result1.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)
          {
           using (var decompressedStream = new GZipStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
          {
           using (var rd = new StreamReader(decompressedStream, enc))
             {
               pictureResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
             }
          }
     }
```

**Below is the Web API code** :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [CompressFilter]
    public HttpResponseMessage SavePictures1(int driverid, string pswd, JObject jsonResult)
    {
     var rawMessage = Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    }
```

**CompressFilter Class:**

```
public class CompressFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {

        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actContext)
        {
            var content = actContext.Response.Content;

            var bytes = content == null ? null : content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
            var zlibbedContent = bytes == null ? new byte[0] :
            CompressionHelper.DeflateByte(bytes);
            actContext.Response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(zlibbedContent);
            actContext.Response.Content.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
            actContext.Response.Content.Headers.Add("Content-encoding", "deflate");
            actContext.Response.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            base.OnActionExecuted(actContext);
        }
    }



     public class CompressionHelper
        {
            public static byte[] DeflateByte(byte[] str)
            {
                if (str == null)
                { return null; }

                ErrorLog.WriteAPIRequest("", "Driver", Convert.ToString(str.Length), "SavePictures", "Test");


                using (var output = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var compressor = new Ionic.Zlib.GZipStream( output, Ionic.Zlib.CompressionMode.Compress,Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestSpeed))
                    {
                        compressor.Write(str, 0, str.Length);
                    }
                    return output.ToArray();
                }

            }
        }
```

I want to check the request content length that i have send from mobile. How can I get the content length in my above code of Web Api code. So i can check the GZip is working and what is the difference in actual JSON and in GZIP. Hope someone can help to get this.

Comment: check the content length header of the request

Comment: some advice. client code is risking deadlock by mixing async-await with `.Result` blocking calls.

Comment: @Nkosi i try many code but not get the result but don't get success.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the raw requests to make your comparison. Something like fiddler or postman would help

Comment: @Nkosi how can i do this.

Comment: @Nkosi for postman and fiddler i don't find find any option from that i can post my gzip json

Comment: No send your request as your did in code and inspect the raw request that was sent using fiddler to make your comparisons about request content length

Comment: @Nkosi actually i try this and not understand how can i check this from xamarin form i am calling my test ip address where i have deployed the code. I can't call local host. on my test server where i have deployed the Web API published file i try but can not attached fiddler to see what request are coming and what is length of the request so i was trying to know the code to know the request content length or request size

Comment: @Nkosi i tried with fiddler i post the my request from mobile this says accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 2091816 . But when i send the normal json then this display same content-length: 2091816 . Is the gzip is not working?